# Raspberry Pi 2 hissing sound only when not connected via HDMI

Tags: audio

My Raspberry Pi 2 (running the latest Raspbian Jessie Lite and with Pixel) is making a hissing sound over the 3.5mm headphone jack only when not connected via HDMI. I have set the audio output device to 3.5mm headphone jack in `raspi-config`.
When it is connected to a screen and boots, it doesn't hiss at all. But when it isn't connected to a screen and boots it hisses as soon as I plug it in.

I've tried most of the available solutions but they do not work.

Comment: You may have used "most of the availble(sic) solutions", but obviously **NOT** the right one. Tell us **EXACTLY** what you did, including cable details.

Comment: I do not feel that cable details are necessary because I have tested the speaker that I am using with the Raspberry Pi connected to a screen but with audio going out of the 3.5mm headphone jack. It just doesn't work if the screen/hdmi cable isn't connected. I have tested this with a pair of apple headphones, unbranded headphones and aux cable. I have also tried setting "disable_audio_dither=1" in /boot/config.txt, constantly play silence (aplay -t raw -r 48000 -c 2 -f S16_LE /dev/zero) and reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 2):

The 3.5 mm audio jack is an analog sound device. The hissing sound most likely comes from the connection between the jack and whatever is plugged in to it. The HDMI port outputs video and sound digitally, so when you plug in the cable the video AND sound are going through the HDMI port most likely.

Comment: However, it doesn't hiss if I have the Raspberry Pi connected to the screen and the audio output is going through the headphone jack.

Comment: I have crackling when I am using apps without audio. I tried to use speakers via the headphone jack and it made no difference ... the audio went though the external speakers but the crackling through the HDMI connection still occurred. I have to mute the TV to stop it.